# New York City weather data

Tags: data-request, weather, noaa

I am looking for daily weather data for New York City. I have searched the NOAA website but could find only the weather data for New York State. It doesn't have many records for New York City Boroughs other than the Manhattan.

Please suggest some links for weather data that covers all the five Boroughs of New York City.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nyc noaa:
http://www.weather.gov/okx/
areas in ny, including some boroughs but i don't see them all:
http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/NY_cc_us.html
historical nyc noaa data:
http://w2.weather.gov/climate/index.php?wfo=okx
wunderground for yesterday 2015-12-05, you can alter dates back to 1943 via omnibox browser command line, aka url ;):
http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KNYC/2015/12/5/DailyHistory.html?req_city=New+York&req_state=NY&req_statename=New+York&reqdb.zip=10001&reqdb.magic=5&reqdb.wmo=99999

Answer (score 2):

You can get custom historical datasets for any geographic region (or stations) in the country from NOAA At:

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search

The National Weather Service has a online API where you can get real-time weather data:

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/survey/pgb_survey/dev/rest.php